# "Variable might not have been initialized" only when multiple constructors are available

Tags: java, android

I have a class where I declare a variable and initialize it in the constructor. when I have one constructor in my code, everything works perfectly fine. The issue occurs when I add another constructor.
Everything is the same in both constructors but only constructor's arguments are different. 
Any idea why this happens?

```
private final NavDrawerManager.OnDrawerItemClickListener mOnDrawerItemClickListener;
private final MoreMenuActivity.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;


public NavMenuAdapter(final List<NavMenuItem> menuItems, final String selectedId, final NavDrawerManager.OnDrawerItemClickListener onDrawerItemClickListener) {
    mMenuItems = menuItems;
    mSelectedId = selectedId;
    mOnDrawerItemClickListener = onDrawerItemClickListener;
}

public NavMenuAdapter(final List<NavMenuItem> menuItems, final String selectedId, final MoreMenuActivity.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    mMenuItems = menuItems;
    mSelectedId = selectedId;
    mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
```

Comment: `Everything is the same in both constructors` - that's not true. `when I have one constructor in my code, everything works perfectly fine` - that's not true either. You need to initialize both final variables (listeners) in constructor.

Comment: What's the issue you're having here?

Comment: Just provide a default constructor where you initialize the variables and call the default constructor from non default constructor with THIS keyword. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Do you *really* need references to such specific types of listener? Is there a common superclass of the two which would allow you to have just one field?

Answer (score 7):

You are declaring attributes as final, but your constructors do not initialize them all.

```
private final NavDrawerManager.OnDrawerItemClickListener mOnDrawerItemClickListener;
private final MoreMenuActivity.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
```

Each time an instance is constructed, it should have initialized **all** final attributes.